# Change the configuration to trigger Email to send out the Automation Test Results

Tags: java, git, email, jakarta-mail

This issue is specific to my project. So I am posting this question with all the details specifically for the issue, I am facing. This wasn't an issue until a week ago when the Email services was shut down.

I am trying to see if somehow a new email services can be utilized to copy the Test results and send out an email to expected stake holders.

So Here's the .bat file which is configured in GIT to be executed through a Jenkins Job. At the last line of this code is the instructions which picks up all the paths set and executes the command to send out the email with the HTML generated at the end of Execution.

```
    :: locations
    @echo on
    @SET HH=%time:~0,2%
    @if "%HH:~0,1%"==" " SET HH=0%HH:~1,1%
    @SET TODAYS_DATETIME=%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%HH%%time:~3,2%
    @SET TEST_SOURCE_DIR=\\CXXXXXXXXA1\CXXXXXPlatform\decepticons\decepticons-MoceboFMS\test-suite
    @SET TEST_RESULTS_DIR=\\CXXXXXXXXA1\CXXXXXPlatform\decepticons\decepticons-MoceboFMS\test-results\regression\DEMO\Chrome\SIGN_IN_%TODAYS_DATETIME%
    @SET TEST_EXECUTION_DIR=C:\TEMPDocebo\Webalt QED Testing

    :: configuration and build files to be used
    @SET QED_TEST_CONFIG=QrtTestConfigMyLearningTestChrome.xml
    @SET ANT_BUILD_FILE=SignInScript.xml
    ::Email Sender
    @SET PLATFORMQED_DIR=\\CXXXXXXXXA1.tww.tintin.com\CXXXXXPlatform\QED\PlatformQEDUtilities
    @SET emailJar="%TEST_EXECUTION_DIR%\lib\emailsender.jar"
    @SET jarLib="%TEST_EXECUTION_DIR%/lib/*"
    @SET emailClass=com.trgr.quality.emailsender.EmailSender
    @SET TESTRUNNAME=Mocebo-Chrome-UI-SignIn 
    @SET ENVIRONMENT=TR_YELLOW_QA
    @SET TESTRUNTYPE=summary
    @SET RECIPIENT=skiran6587@gmail.com

    :: delete the temp test execution location
    rmdir /S /Q "%TEST_EXECUTION_DIR%"

    :: make the temp location
    if not exist "%TEST_EXECUTION_DIR%"\ mkdir "%TEST_EXECUTION_DIR%"

    :: copy regression tests, ant builds, external libraries, and resources locally
    xcopy /y "%TEST_SOURCE_DIR%"\* "%TEST_EXECUTION_DIR%" /s /i

    :: overwrite QrtTestConfig.xml as necessary
    copy /y "%TEST_EXECUTION_DIR%"\resources\configs\%QED_TEST_CONFIG% "%TEST_EXECUTION_DIR%"\resources\configs\QrtTestConfig.xml
    @echo.
    :: execute the tests
    cd /d "%TEST_EXECUTION_DIR%"
    call ant -buildfile "%TEST_EXECUTION_DIR%"\ant\\"%ANT_BUILD_FILE%"

:: create test results datetime directory for results
    if not exist "%TEST_RESULTS_DIR%"\ mkdir "%TEST_RESULTS_DIR%"

:: copy test results and configuration to QED NAS
    xcopy /y "%TEST_EXECUTION_DIR%"\test-results\* "%TEST_RESULTS_DIR%" /s /i
    copy /y "%TEST_EXECUTION_DIR%"\resources\configs\QrtTestConfig.xml "%TEST_RESULTS_DIR%"

:: copy down latest email sender jar
    @SET EMAIL_SENDER_DIR=\\CXXXXXXXXA1\CXXXXXPlatform\QED\PlatformQEDUtilities\email-sender\latest
    copy /y "%EMAIL_SENDER_DIR=%\emailsender.jar" "%TEST_EXECUTION_DIR%\lib"

:: Email Results
    java -cp %emailJar% %emailClass% %TESTRUNNAME% %TESTRUNTYPE% %TEST_RESULTS_DIR% %RECIPIENT% false
```

The DNS Request had no response.

```
C:\temp>nslookup
Default Server:  eagp-weeidns01.ton.xxxxcompany.com
Address:  10.XXX.XX.9

> mail: mail2-top.xxxxcompany.com
Server:  mail2-top.xxxxcompany.com
Address:  143.XXX.XX.8

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to mail2-top.xxxxcompany.com timed-out
```

Please suggest for any mail service which can be utilized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was your email server shut down **permanently** and you're looking for a replacement email service?  Try Gmail.

Or are you looking for a way to send email even when your email server is shut down **temporarily**?  The simplest approach is to have an email server running on your local machine that can queue the messages until the real email server is available.

Comment: I am looking for a way to send out an email as the email server which we were using is shut down permanently. Could you suggest me a way to have an email server running on my local server that can replace the one I had earlier?

Comment: There are [lots of email servers available](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#servers) to run locally, both free versions and paid products.  I'm sure you can figure out how to use google to find them.  Note that running your own email server can be non-trivial and you're often better off using a service you pay for.

Comment: Thanks, Bill Shannon for your suggestions.